# How to dynamically align views in Xamarin Mono for Android in RelativeLayout

Tags: c#, android, mono, android-relativelayout, xamarin

I searched a lot before I decided to ask the question here...
What I'm trying to achieve is dynamic creation of layout, that basically a rows with some content...
I designed the template as axml layout. Here it is:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_height="91dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="68.524dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5" />
<TextView
    android:text="Год: "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1" />
<TextView
    android:text="Жанр: "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView4" />
<TextView
    android:text="Оценка: "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView5"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView5"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView6" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView5"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView7"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5" />
```

I tried to create this dynamically in code, but all the elements is on top of each other...
Here is the code:

```
private void _buildUI(AnimeList anList)
    {
        var i = 1;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        foreach (var anime in anList)
        {
            RelativeLayout wrapper = new RelativeLayout(this);
            wrapper.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
            img.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(68, 90);
            img.Id = i;
            img.SetImageURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(anime.Image.Url));
            wrapper.AddView(img);

            TextView title = new TextView(this);
            textParams.SetMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, img.Id);
            title.LayoutParameters = textParams;
            i++;
            title.Id = i;
            title.Text = anime.Title;
            wrapper.AddView(title);

            TextView yearTitle = new TextView(this);
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, title.Id);
            i++;
            yearTitle.Id = i;
            yearTitle.Text = "Год: ";
            yearTitle.LayoutParameters = textParams;
            wrapper.AddView(yearTitle);

            TextView year = new TextView(this);
            year.Text = anime.Information.Year;
            i++;
            year.Id = i;
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, yearTitle.Id);
            year.LayoutParameters = textParams;
            wrapper.AddView(year);

            TextView genreTitle = new TextView(this);
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, year.Id);
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, img.Id);
            genreTitle.LayoutParameters = textParams;
            genreTitle.Text = "Жанр: ";
            i++;
            genreTitle.Id = i;
            wrapper.AddView(genreTitle);

            TextView genre = new TextView(this);
            genre.Text = anime.Information.Genre;
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, genreTitle.Id);
            genre.LayoutParameters = textParams;
            i++;
            genre.Id = i;
            wrapper.AddView(genre);

            TextView gradeTitle = new TextView(this);
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, img.Id);
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, genre.Id);
            gradeTitle.LayoutParameters = textParams;
            gradeTitle.Text = "Оценка: ";
            i++;
            gradeTitle.Id = i;
            wrapper.AddView(gradeTitle);

            TextView grade = new TextView(this);
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, gradeTitle.Id);
            grade.LayoutParameters = textParams;
            grade.Text = anime.Rating.Grade;
            i++;
            grade.Id = i;
            wrapper.AddView(grade);

            TextView votes = new TextView(this);
            textParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, grade.Id);
            votes.Text = string.Format("( {0} )", anime.Rating.Votes);
            i++;
            votes.Id = i;
            wrapper.AddView(votes);

            LinearLayout linearList = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearList);
            linearList.AddView(wrapper);
            i++;
        }
```

Can anyone help me to solve that problem? Where is my mistake?

> Sovled!

I tried to reinvent the wheel over there... What I needed to do is to use ListView and custom row layout. It is well documented in Xamarin website - [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance).

Comment: You should submit the link as an answer and accept it so the question gets marked as answered.